# Different ways of disabling controls within a css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webforms

Can someone tell me all possible ways to disable all buttons in a class, I already tried this which isn't working,

```
$("input.myClass").attr('disabled', true);
```

This is how I am using it,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var objA = $get('<%= checkbox.ClientID %>');

            $(objA).change(function() {

                if($(this).is(':checked'))
                {  
                    $(".anotherClass").sortable('disable'); //works
                    $("input.myClass").prop('disabled', 'disabled'); //doesn't work
                }
```

CSS is quiet simple,

```
.myClass
{
    float: left; 
    width: 140px; 
    margin-left: 4px; 
    margin-right: 4px; 
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML looks like this,

```
    <div class="myClass">
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="bbb" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="return false;" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" Text="aaa" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="return false;" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="button" OnClick="bt_Click" />
    </div>
```

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "in a class". A number of interpretations are possible.

Comment: *after seeing the HTML* .... as I suspected, "in a class" means "in a container selectable by class"!

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004885/attrdisabled-disabled-issue

Comment: @Shekhar I can't see disabled attribute for myClass

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot sorry but I didn't get that

Comment: The only `myClass` in sight is applied to the container, therefore `$(".myClass input").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot you was telling me right thing, but you missed ":" between class and input, thanks though :)

Comment: But there shouldn't be a `:`. What does it achieve?

Comment: Actually, it's hard to tell what ASP, bless it, actually serves. Maybe ` $(".myClass button").prop('disabled', true);` would be better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery disable by class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458466/jquery-disable-by-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".myClass :input").attr('disabled', true);
```

is the only code that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery 1.6+

To change the disabled property you should use the .prop() function.

```
$("input.myclass").prop('disabled', true);
$("input.myclass").prop('disabled', false);
```

jQuery 1.5 and below

The .prop() function doesn't exist, but .attr() does similar:

Set the disabled attribute.

```
$("input.myclass").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable again

```
$("input.myclass").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Referred From : [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/how-to-disable-an-input-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("input.myClass").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you want to disable all button type inputs inside div with `myClass` class:

```
$(".myClass input[type=button]").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle of it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `attr()`, use this:

```
$("input.myClass").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Or `prop()`:

```
$("input.myClass").prop('disabled', true);
```

**In regard to updated question:**

1. Change your script tag to `<script>`
2. Place it towards the bottom of the page (not in the head section)

Answer (score 1):

To disable

```
$('input.myClass').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

// To enable

```
$('input.myClass').removeAttr('disabled');
```

// OR you can set attr to ""

```
$('input.myClass').attr('disabled', '');
```

Some SO Links

[jQuery disable/enable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594952/jquery-disable-enable-submit-button)

[JQuery - Set Attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009609/jquery-set-attribute-value)
[.attr("disabled", "disabled") issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004885/attrdisabled-disabled-issue)
[Toggle input disabled attribute using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702000/toggle-input-disabled-attribute-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

since you asked all possible ways and the common ones are out there you can always prevent default by doing:

```
$('input.myClass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

preventing default, prevents from submitting a form for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $("input[type='button']").attr("disabled","disabled"); to disable all buttons.